# Can't make Alamofire run in the simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, alamofire

i have installed alamo fire and cannot seem to make a request with it.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let groupLogin = groupUserNameEntry.text;
    let groupPassword = groupPasswordEntry.text;
    print("line of debug code before request")

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.myserver.com/folks/authenticate", parameters: ["login": groupLogin!, "password": groupPassword!])
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            print("line of debug code inside request")
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
   }
```

when run in the simulator i get the first line of debug code before request but the output in the "All Output" viewer is (lldb), which i understand to mean low level debugger. It seems like the request is not getting made, but there is no error output. The url works fine in a browser.

Comment: That means your app has stopped running because of a crash or a breakpoint. In the code editor, it should show a highlighted line of code showing you where it stopped. If you post it, it will be easier to find the problem.

Comment: thanks for the debug advice, Clever Error

Answer (score 1):

The `text` of a `UITextField` is an optional value, so what you are doing is assigning to `groupLogin` an optional value, but `groupLogin` is not an optional value type, so everything breaks.

You need to safely unwrap optional values, there're many ways to achieve this, but in my opinion `guard` is the best:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let groupLogin = groupUserNameEntry.text else {
        print("groupUserNameEntry.text is nil, stop execution")
        return
    }

    guard let groupPassword = groupPasswordEntry.text else {
        print("groupPasswordEntry.text is nil, stop execution")
        return
    }
    print("line of debug code before request")

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.myserver.com/folks/authenticate", parameters: ["login": groupLogin, "password": groupPassword])
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            print("line of debug code inside request")
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
 }
```

Comment: thanks, i used your selection, but got exactly the same result. Even when i put my own values in for login and password by making them strings, i only get lldb as the result in the Output viewer

Comment: nevermind, that problem was unrelated. Your suggestion helped me a lot. Thanks for clearing up my confusion.